# groupby for dictionary of lists with multiple columns without pandas

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by

I am working on a question that process data without using pandas.
I use dictionary of list data to read CSV data.

```
product year  complaints
'A'     2002  'bla'
'A'     2003   ''
'B'     2003   ''
'C'     2004  'blabla'
```

have the data look like

```
data = {'product': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
'year':[2002, 2003, 2003, 2004]
'complaints': ['bla', '', '', 'blabla']
}
```

How can I create the groupby table based on both year and product like this?

```
product year  total_complaints
A       2002   1
A       2003   0
B       2003   0
C       2004   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested dictionary to quickly tabulate the counts. The `defaultdict` builtin makes this really easy.

```py
from functools import partial
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, lambda *args, **kwargs: 0))
for row in records:
    product = row.get('product', None)
    if product is not None:
        pd = d[product]
        year = row.get('year', None)
        if year is not None:
            pd[year] += 1
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change the way you are keeping the data to something like this:

```
data = {
    'A': { '2002': ['bla'], '2003': [] },
    'B': { '2003': [] },
    'C': { '2004': ['blablabla'] },
}
```

Then to show the table grouped by complaints:

```
for product, years in data.items():
    for year, complaints in years.items():
        print(f'{product}\t{year}\t{len(complaints)}')
```

output:

```
A       2002    1
A       2003    0
B       2003    0
C       2004    1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a dictionary using (product, year) as the key:

```
data = {'product': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
'year':[2002, 2003, 2003, 2004],
'complaints': ['bla', '', '', 'blabla']
}

# convert dictionaries to array
dd = list(zip(data['product'], data['year'], data['complaints']))

# distinct keys
keys = set(zip(data['product'], data['year']))

# totals storage
ttl = {x:0 for x in keys}

# Tally totals by key (product\year)
for d in dd:   
    ttl[(d[0],d[1])] += 1 if d[2] else 0

print (ttl)
```

Output

```
{('A', 2003): 0, ('B', 2003): 0, ('C', 2004): 1, ('A', 2002): 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame GroupBy effectively creates a logical (hash) key from the columns/fields provided as arguments. The below approach artificially replicates this by 'manually' creating the logical key by constructing a unique string using an defined delimiter. The logical key is then used to aggregate the counts using a dictionary. (Note: This logical construction is simple. It is not intended to be perfect. For example, it will fail if your products contain the "::" delimiter. There are ways to work around this; dictionaries support tuple keys...)

If the expectation is to have a tabular output, then a secondary step is necessary to deconstruct the keys and flatten out the structure. Below I provide an example of how to create list of tuples (i.e. DataFrame input).

```
agg_res = {} 
for (prod, yr, comp) in zip(data["product"], data["year"], data["complaints"]):
    count = 1
    if comp is None or comp == "":
        count = 0
    prod_yr = "{0}::{1}".format(prod, yr)
    if prod_yr not in agg_res.keys():
        agg_res[prod_yr] = count
    else:
        agg_res[prod_yr] += count
tbl = []
for k, v in agg_res.items():
    a = k.split("::")
    tbl.append( (a[0], int(a[1]), v) )
```

In your example, a group with an empty string still exists with a zero count. Was that intended?